# How to loop hex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, hex

In C, the output is what I expect. In Javascript, the output is not what I expect. In Javascript, the hex loops in decimal not in hexadecimal.

C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
for(int i=0x1000;i<=0x109F;i++){
    printf("%x\n",i);
}
return 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i=0x1000;i<=0x109F;i++){
document.write(i+"<br>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: A Number is stored as Number, it doesn't matter the notation you're using to specify it. For instance, if you dump `0x10` or `020`, you're threat the same value (`16`), and only the value is stored, the notation is a convention that makes easier threats some numbers in some condition. What you need is to format the output, as @Doorknob suggested, and as you have done in C using `printf("%x")`. It really doesn't matter that you specified `i=0x1000`, having `i=4096` will leads to the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `toString` method:

```
document.write(i.toString(16)+"<br>"); //base 16 (hex)
```